# How can you spectate a player with non-standard characters in their username?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm trying to spectate a player with non-standard characters in their username. How can I do this?

I've tried mouse-selecting and copying the username, but even when pasting it into  the console command `spec_player`, it isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried cycling through all players?  I don't remember how to do that, but it should show you each player.

Comment: @MBraedley - Left/Right click on the mouse to go forward/back when spectating IIRC

Comment: @Robotnik yeah, that sounds about right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't spectate a player using console commands, you could always do it the manual way through the UI:

1. Press <kbd>.</kbd> and join team spectate (the little TV screen)
2. Left click to cycle through each player until you find the specific person you want to spectate. If you accidentally pass them or they die, you can right click to cycle backwards through each player.

You can also use <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle first person and third person view.

Comment: Best option IMHO.

Comment: Had no idea you could press space to do that.  Thank you very much.